# Fortran array assignment when the subscripts are not in the same order

Tags: arrays, fortran, variable-assignment

How can I accomplish an array assignment when the subscripts are not in the same order? I tried

```
scansDC(1:nRadii, iScanF, 1:nSpeciesDC) = b(1:nSpeciesDC, 1:nRadii)
```

but, although this compiles and runs without error, it gives the wrong result.

The intent is to copy `b(iSpeciesDC, iRadius)` to `scansDC(iRadius, iScanF, iSpeciesDC)` for `1 <= iSpeciesDC <= nSpeciesDC` and `1 <= iRadius<= nRadii`.

Compiler is Intel Fortran XE 2015.

Answer (score 1):

```
INTEGER :: i, j
FORALL (i=1:nRadii, j=1:nSpeciesDC) scansDC(i,iScanF,j) = b(j,i)
```

Comment: This will work (it's the parallelization of nested DO loops), but I was looking for something using array assignment.

Comment: FORALL is a form of array assignment.  Semantically it is not a do loop - consider the case where the left and right hand sides of a child *forall-assignment-stmt* overlap.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your original attempt

```
scansDC(1:nRadii, iScanF, 1:nSpeciesDC) = b(1:nSpeciesDC, 1:nRadii)
```

gave a different answer than you wanted is because there's no reason for your compiler to infer that you want the transpose taken of b just because the `1:nRadii` and `1:nSpeciesDC`
ranges are switched around.  The array ranges are compatible, so the data is just copied over in linear order, giving you the transpose of what you want.

If you need the data copied over in a  different order, you need to specify that, either by doing the copy fairly explicitly, as in IanH's correct answer, or by explicitly asking for a transpose:

```
program test

    integer, parameter :: nradii=10, nspeciesDC=2
    integer, dimension(nradii, 5, nspeciesDC) :: scansDC
    integer, dimension(nspeciesDC, nradii) :: b
    integer :: i,j,k
    integer, parameter :: iscanf = 2

    scansDC = 0
    k = 0
    do i=1,nradii
        do j=1,nspeciesDC
            b(j,i) = k
            k = k + 1
        enddo
    enddo
    print *, b

    scansDC(1:nRadii, iScanF, 1:nSpeciesDC) = transpose(b(1:nspeciesDC, 1:nRadii))   

    print *,scansDC(:,iScanF,:)
end program test
```

Comment: OK, I see. Thank you both for your suggestions. It seems there's no way to do this that doesn't involve either specifying the loop, or doing an expensive matrix transpose. I guess it's too much to ask of a compiler to recognize the similarity of the subscript bounds, which is lost as soon as the symbols are replaced by their values.

Comment: @Woody20 : The "expensive matrix transpose" has to be done anyway - that's what switching the order of indices _is_. The only question that remains is: how do you want to express it.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to do this to use the transpose intrinsic.

```
scansDC(1:nRadii, iScanF, 1:nSpeciesDC) = TRANSPOSE(b(1:nSpeciesDC, 1:nRadii))
```